# How to only add content in the first type element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add content with :before, only for the first "small" element but my current code only adds the content before all the "small" elements?

```css
small:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: 'ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY ';
  color: #cc3300;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="bold_help_text"><small> first text content!</small></span></div>
<div class="option_textbox">
  <span class="bold_help_text"><small>second text content!</small></span>
```

I expect the text "ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY" to be in the first "small" element but it appears in both.

Comment: Both of the `small` elements are the first of their type within their parent elements.

Comment: How do I target the small element or the first bold_help_text class? I think this is the issue too, I target both the small elements at the moment

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer:

According to the OP'S source code, the following change should fulfuil the OP's requirement:

From:

```
.bold_help_text>small:before {
    ...
}
```

To:

```
.bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:before {
    ...
}
```

---

## Original Answer:

Demo:

```css
.container > div:first-of-type small:before {
  content: 'ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY ';
  color: #cc3300;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span class="bold_help_text">
      <small> first text content!</small>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="option_textbox">
    <span class="bold_help_text">
      <small>second text content!</small>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In nutshell, I'm looking at the first div child of the `.container` and then look for its `small` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I don't have the "div" elements after the container. When I tried this code it did not work (I can only edit the CSS file, not add the extra div elements you did)

Comment: The problem with your code is that `small` elements doesn't share the same parent/ancestor.

Comment: How do I achieve the end result you did? The problem is that I can't just edit the .bold_help_text element because I have multi in my HTML code. But I want to add some content in front the first time it's used.

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: Yes, I did manage to copy it to codepen. Please have a look here https://codepen.io/karl-feldt/pen/YzKGzPy Please note I just copied that element I'm currently having since the landing page isnt online at the moment

Comment: You could also visit this page, (made it online lol) https://wildpurpose.com/pages/ambassador-package

Comment: @KalleFeldt see my updated answer.

Comment: Omg, that did it! Thank you so much for your time!!